# variant of young's inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, young-inequality

Let $\alpha_{i}\geq 0$ y $p_{i}\geq 0$ for $i=1,2,...,n$ such that:
$$\frac{1}{p_1}+\frac{1}{p_2}+...+\frac{1}{p_n}=1$$
proof that:

$$\alpha_1\alpha_2...\alpha_n\leq \frac{\alpha_1^{p_1}}{p_1}+\frac{\alpha_2^{p_2}}{p_2}+...+\frac{\alpha_n^{p_n}}{p_n}$$
I have been trying to perform this test analogously to the proof of Young's inequality but I have not been able to get it

Comment: That's the [weighted AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Weighted_AM%E2%80%93GM_inequality) for $\,\alpha_k^{p_k}\,$ with weights $\,\frac{1}{p_k}\,$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can prove this via induction over $n$.

Comment: Can you say me, What would the induction hypothesis look like?

Comment: The induction hypothesis with $n \in \mathbb N$ is the following: if $\alpha_i \ge 0$, $p_i > 0$, $i = 1,\ldots, n$, with $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i^{-1} = 1$, then $$\prod_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \le \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^{p_i}/p_i.$$